# How to render a partial on button-click in rails using javascript and not by using a method in controller?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, partial

I have a issue where I need to render a partial on a button click say do u really want to perfrom the action and it has to be done by using only javascript, adding a method in the controller and thereby rendering the partial is not preferable.

Comment: well, its this way, I don't want to send any request to controller but at the same time I need to push the html content in the partial to a custom dialog box.

Comment: If that's the case, you can only pre-render the content as suggested by Agarwal, however that method is limited to simple use cases.

Comment: since its a simple use case I have followed the below method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply load the partial and just hide it with CSS using display:none and when the users clicks on the button show him the confirm dialog and change the CSS of the partial from none to block and you are done

Comment: can u suggest me some other alternative this does the job but i want it to render it in a custom dialog box that i have already created.

Comment: What about if you need the form to be for a new object each time the form is brought up?